# How can I change GNOME Shell theme?

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-shell

I've installed the GNOME Shell in Ubuntu 12.04 and I want to change the "Shell Theme", But it doesn't allow me to do that.

The alert says something like: "The GNOME-Shell extension is not activated", and I want to install it with the console, But it returns me an error.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 29):

Follow these steps:

**Install GNOME Shell extensions & GNOME Tweak Tool:**

- Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions gnome-tweak-tool
  ```

**Download GNOME Shell Theme:**

You can find lots of GNOME Shell themes on [Gnome-Look.org](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=191)

**How to change the GNOME Shell theme?**

- Once installed, Click on Activities on top panel and search for "Advanced Settings" (or "Tweaks" or "Tweak Tool") and open it.
- Under *Shell Extensions* enable **User Themes** extension (if it's not installed, you can install it from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/)) by clicking on **ON/OFF** switch.

[image]

- Close 'GNOME Tweak Tool' and reopen it, Open themes settings, Click on browse button in front of **Shell Theme** and select your custom theme, Once updated click on drop down menu in front of browse button and select your theme. You'll see the changes take effect immediately. That's it!

[image]

Comment: `gnome-shell-extensions` does not appear to be available in 12.04. Do you know how to obtain it?

Comment: @detly is it not installed by default? Install gnome tweak tool, can you see the shell extensions tab in it?

Comment: @levesque - I eventually found it on the website, but it takes a bit of work to get it to install on 12.04!

Comment: Should I extract the zip or navigate to the zip?