# Cannot install extensions required for GNOME Shell themes

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I keep getting this output:

```
 soham@fortress:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions gnome-tweak-tool    
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree      
    Reading state information... Done    
    gnome-tweak-tool is already the newest version.
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      gnome-shell-extensions
    0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.
    1 not fully installed or removed.
    Need to get 0 B/121 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 849 kB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
    (Reading database ... 179291 files and directories currently installed.)
    Unpacking gnome-shell-extensions (from .../gnome-shell-extensions_3.4.1~git20120508.dfd7191a-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz0_all.deb) ...
    dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-shell-extensions_3.4.1~git20120508.dfd7191a-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz0_all.deb (--unpack):
     trying to overwrite '/usr/share/locale/lv/LC_MESSAGES/gnome-shell-extensions.mo', which is also in package gnome-shell-extensions-common 3.2.0-0ubuntu1~oneiric1
    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already                                                                  
    dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-shell-extensions_3.4.1~git20120508.dfd7191a-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz0_all.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Update: Fixed that. Now GNOME Tweak Tool shows me an exclamation mark beside the extension enable button, saying "Extension doesn't support shell version". My GNOME shell is already the latest version. Help!

Comment: I think I'm using a wrong repo or that all the repos have Oneiric packages. ?

Comment: See if this helps you: [How can I change Gnome Shell theme?](http://askubuntu.com/a/141448/37006)

Answer (score 0):

Use the gnome-shell-extensions package from 
[gnome's launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/gnome).

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

to force the install of the packages that didn't get installed because of the error. Then, run the installation command again.

Then, `apt-get -f install` back and forth. Most probably you'll get through.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GNOME 3.6, it's normal if you receive:

```
Extension doesn't support shell version
```

Because GNOME 3.6 it's too new so the developer will need to rewrite it to make it support with the new version.