# How to install Hooli theme (or any other in fact)?

Tags: themes

I've been trying to install the Hooli theme for Ubuntu 18.04.1, but I can't seem to do it. I do have Docky, but it also glitches out. I did get told by one friend (who is good at Ubuntu) that gnome3 doesn't like docks, but I don't know how to fix this! I also don't want to ask him all the time.

Can someone tell me how to do it? Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:** Alright, I've been redirected to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141277/how-can-i-change-gnome-shell-theme) topic, and I've checked it. I installed everything, but I don't know where to put the extensions folder. Can someone now just help me there?
To clarify what I mean with "extensions folder",

here is a screenshot of my downloads folder
[image: here is a screenshot of my downloads folder.]

"Hooli" is the theme I would like to install, the master folder is the folder I got from one of the answers.

Comment: can you share the link for the theme you are trying to install?

Comment: Theme coming right up! https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1102901/

I chose this one because it looks like Mac and I generally like it, but any other would work too.

Comment: I'll definitely check that one out. If it works, what should I do with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inorder to have the similar look which is in your linked page.
you need to have Hooli Gnome Shell Theme & MacOS sierra Icon Themes.

Download those from below links.

https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1102901/startdownload?file_id=1493631666&file_name=Hooli.zip&file_type=application/zip&file_size=247431

https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1210856/startdownload?file_id=1543864792&file_name=v0.8.6.2.tar.gz&file_type=application/x-gzip&file_size=33719904

[image]

Right Click them and `Extract Here`

[image]

[image]

now you have required folders.
1. `Macos-sierra-CT-0.8.6.2` which is for icons theming.
2. `Hooli` which is for User Shell theming.

we need to put these folders into either `home` folder or in `/usr/share/.......`

i will explain to put it in home folder.

first check in the home folder, `.themes` & `.icons` folders exist or not.
to see hidden files press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. it should show files & folders that starts with .(dot)

if `.themes` & `.icons` folders are not there, create them.

[image]

now put `Macos-sierra-CT-0.8.6.2` folder in `.icons` folder
& `Hooli` folder in `.themes` folder

[image]
[image]

you have successfully installed the `icon` & `User Shell` Themes.

you need to choose them. how to?

for this easiest, way is to install `gnome-tweaks` if you have not yet installed, install it by
`sudo apt update && sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

you also need to install `User Themes` extension, install it from Ubuntu Software.

Now, open `gnome-tweaks` and select the icon & user shell theme.

[image]

[image]

Comment: One more thing, since I'm the ultimate Ubuntu noob: how do I make my dock look exactly like in the GIFs you kindly posted for me? [Currently, they're as if I don't have a theme.](https://imgur.com/mBD9p1v)

Comment: install `dash to dock` extension from Ubuntu software.