# Adding a login screen background using .themes folder

Tags: 18.04, themes, gnome-shell

Looks like modding Gnome shell at usr/share/gnome-shell/theme is not a good idea. As a workaround, I tried copying the `Adapta` theme folder from usr/share/theme and placed a copy in `.themes` folder in the `Home` folder.

But after that when I edit the `gnome-shell.css` and placed an alternative image on the same folder, it won't change the background. It fetches whatever is available at usr/share/gnome-shell/theme folder. Why is it so ? I even placed an edited copy of `ubuntu.css` next to `gnome-shell.css` and in the root folder of the theme in `.themes`. But still whatever is in the gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css works. Is there any fix ?

I want to change the login screen user icon as well. It is more comfortable if I can do it through `.themes` folder. Thanks.

I changed this in ubuntu.css

```
#lockDialogGroup {
  background: #2c001e url(resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/noise-texture.png);
  background-repeat: repeat; }
```

to

```
#lockDialogGroup {
  background: #2c001e url(unlock-background.jpeg);
  background-repeat: repeat; }
```

Comment: Please post (at least the relevant part of) your `.css` file to the question. A couple of questions: 1. did you use the absolute path to the image file? 2. Did you reboot/re-login after making changes?

Comment: The login screen uses resources://..noise-texture.png for the background. I used the same CSS on usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css by changing the image to bg.jpeg and path as url(bg.jpeg). it works when I use it on gnome-shell/theme but not when I place the same ubuntu.css in .themes folder. Yes, I tired switching off and switching ON. Thought it will be more perfect than rebooting.

Comment: It would great to know whether the ubuntu.css in usr/share/gnome-shell/theme will discard whatever we place on `.themes` folder. I used the same file on both locations.

Comment: I will post the altered ubuntu.css file in a few hours. Currently on a different machine. What I am trying to say is if we place the same modified `ubuntu.css` file in gnome-shell/theme and .themes/adapta/gnome-shell , the one in gnome-shell/theme is the only one that works. It completely discards whatever we place in the `.themes` folder

Comment: Did you **select** the custom shell theme (e.g. using GNOME Tweaks)?

Comment: I selected `Adapted` from Tweaks. That is the name I gave to the modification to avoid confusion. I did the same way we switch themes using the Tweak tool. Are you referring to something else ? Thanks. @PRATAP I will try to read your solution and update. :)

Comment: Thanks @PRATAP . I am able to do what I want using gnome-shell/theme . I am trying to make it work through `.themes`. You have really worked on it by the looks of it :)

Comment: @pomsky How can I add a CSS file to the question ? When I tried in Tweaks, there is no option to change the shell theme. There is a Yellow triangle and the option is greyed out. Maybe as @PRATAP mentioned, we will have to break the link between `gdm3.css` and `ubuntu.css`

Comment: You need to have **User Themes** extension enabled to load a shell the from home directory: https://askubuntu.com/questions/141277/how-can-i-change-gnome-shell-theme  Also you don't have to add the complete `.css` file, just add the part you modified and the corresponding unmodified part.

Comment: Do I need to use UserThemes extension and change the shell theme even if I have modified gnome-shell.css to a working theme ? I have added the CSS changes. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, change your background url from `background: #2c001e url(unlock-background.jpeg);` to `background: #2c001e url(file:///full/path/to/unlock-background.jpeg);`.

Comment: The same. It is fetching what is given in usr/share/..

Comment: IMO a per-user configuration of GDM doesn't make sense because, well, there is no user logged in before a user logs in, and there is no user specific context when switching users either. If two users had different custom GDM themes in their home folder, which one should be chosen?

Comment: @PRATAP you're right. I just wanted to point out why it's reasonable that the `.themes` folder in a user's home directory is not considered in situations when there is no specific user, like before login and when switching users. I also don't like encouraging users to store system configurations in their home folder using symlinks. It's probably not a problem to do this with `gdm3.css` (using `update-alternatives`, of course) , but imagine what could happen if people started symlinking e.g. udev rules to their home folder.

Comment: @danzel The whole reason I asked the question is because I found noise-texture.png for lock screen in the Adapta theme folder.