# I can't change "Shell theme" in Ubuntu

Tags: themes

I Cant change the Shell theme.

I'm new at Ubuntu, someone help

[image]

Comment: you need to install gnome-shell-extension called "user themes"

Comment: @UnKNOWn There is an 8-year old answer in https://askubuntu.com/questions/141277/how-can-i-change-gnome-shell-theme which is still fully correct today.

Comment: @UnKNOWn probably taking negligible disk space. I never bothered about that. Of course, you indeed can install only the User Themes extension using the Gnome Extensions website. Using the repository, however, is safer because that is the version that is tested to work with your system.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1

Install `chrome-gnome-shell` by command `sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell`

Step 2

Check if `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` package is installed, else install it

Step 3

Open `https://extensions.gnome.org/` in Firefox and search for the extension name `User Themes` and install that (do match the gnome shell version there)

Step 4

Open `gnome-tweaks` and go to Extensions tab, you'll see it available now.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I already did it guys, but still there is no option for "User themes extension" follow the print:

[image]

Comment: Close Tweaks and Extensions application. Restart GNOME using Alt+F2, type `r` and press Enter. If still you can't see user themes, try re-logging or rebooting.

Comment: Thanks man, its works. And thanks  to everybody