# How do I make Ubuntu 22.04 Dock more rounded and change border color?

Tags: gnome, themes, dock

Is there some easy way I can make the Dock for Ubuntu 22.04 more rounded like setting a CSS property `border-radius: 999px` and also I would like to change the border color. I cannot find a GNOM extension to do this. Also I did not find options in dconf for these settings either.

[image]

Comment: I answered a question similar to yours here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1451046/how-do-i-modify-the-default-gnome-theme/1451064#1451064

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @alejandro I was able to change the Dock theme and here are the exact steps I took to do it *(in case anyone else wants it).*

1. Install the GNOME [User Themes](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/) extension (if it is not installed already)
2. I activated the Yaru Dark theme (for shell) *(choose any theme you want as your base)*
3. Edit your theme's `gnome-shell.css` file (in my case it was located at `/usr/share/themes/Yaru-dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`)

In the case of Yaru-dark there was already some CSS code specific for styling the Ubuntu Dock (classes starting with `#dashtodockContainer`) and I changed the border-radius from 18px to 999px everywhere and also I added `border-color: transparent !important` under `#dashtodockContainer.bottom #dash .dash-background`

Now my Dock looks much better like this:
[image]